# Third level drop down css wont show & content/links are out of order?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, menu

Some of the sub menu links of the third level are being shown in the second level while some of the second level content are not shown at all. On top of that, I don't know how to get the third level to appear at all. I'm sorry, I'm very new to this.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Bio</li>
    <li>Portfolio
        <ul>
            <li>Design</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Illustartor</li>
                <li>InDesign</li>
                <li>Photoshop</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Media</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Photography</li>
                <li>Video</li>
            </ul>
            <li>Traditional</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Paintings</li>
                <li>Drawings</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  top: 400px;
  index-z: 3;

}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 141px;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
   -webkit-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: delay .5s ease-in-out;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;

}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

li ul li ul{   /* Third Level & beyond ***********/
    display:none;
    background:#55aa7f;
}
li ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    border-left:solid 3px #fff;
    top:0;
    width:auto;
}
li ul li ul li{
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border-top:solid 3px #fff;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
li ul li ul li:hover span{
    color:#fff;
    }

.levelThreeAlign{position:relative;}
```

Comment: Are you able to paste a screenshot of what it is doing?  That would be really helpful.

Comment: You can't have `ul` tags as children of `ul` tags.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I seem to remember doing that before without an issue.

Comment: @user3612261 does this look like what you are seeing?  http://jsfiddle.net/CDc4w/

Comment: Following dmikester1's fiddle, if you add the ul in the li instead of the ul, as Utkanos said, there is a 3 level drop down menu available.

Comment: The HTML is invalid as the parent `li` are bing closed  **before** the submenu `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have closed each list item in the submenu before the ul for the sub-submenu.
html should look like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/FBKm4/1/):

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Bio</li>
    <li>Portfolio
        <ul>
            <li>Design
                <ul>
                    <li>Illustartor</li>
                    <li>InDesign</li>
                    <li>Photoshop</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Media
                <ul>
                    <li>Photography</li>
                    <li>Video</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Traditional
                <ul>
                    <li>Paintings</li>
                    <li>Drawings</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

I have changed some of the css in the fiddle as well utilizing direct descendent selectors.  Inheritance is very important here.  when you style `ul li {` that will cascade down to `ul li ul li {` as you are styling all `li` that are children of a `ul`.  doesn't matter how many levels deep.